# python - boolean mask on array of custom objects

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy-ndarray

Let's suppose I have defined the following class:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
        self.alive = True

    def __repr__(self,):
        return f"t = {self.time:.2E}"
```

And then I have a `numpy.ndarray` of `Event` objects, sorted by time:

```
timestamps
>>>> array([t = 5.00E-11, t = 1.51E-08, t = 3.15E-08, t = 4.69E-08], dtype=object)
```

I want to select for example all the array elements that have the `time` field between two values, and set their `alive` field to `False`.

Is there a way to do it?

The only thing I tried is with an explicit for loop, but this can become really slow:

```
for i in range(len(timestamps)):
  # ...
  # element i get selected
  for j in range(i, len(timestamps):
    if timestamps[i].time < timestamps[j].time < timestamps[i].time + t_dead:
      tiemstamps[j].alive = False
```

while I am looking for something like

```
target = timestamps[i].time
timestamps[target < timestamps.time < target + t_dead].alive = False
# I know the syntax is very wrong here
```

Comment: Have you already looked into [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows you to compare custom objects. Note `__lt__` and `__gt__` implementation.

Edit: As of OP's comment I suggest a few non-for-loop options to set the living flag. Note the new "living" function of Event class.

```
import numpy as np

class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
        self.alive = True

    def __repr__(self,):
        return f"t = {self.time:.2E}"

    # this allows you to check equality of two custom objects
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.time == other.time

    # this allows you to check "less than" property of two custom objects
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.time < other.time

    # this allows you to check "greater than" property of two custom objects
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.time > other.time

    def living(self, is_alive: bool):
        self.alive = is_alive

timestamps = np.array([Event(1), Event(2), Event(3)])

# filtered timestamps
result = timestamps[(timestamps>Event(1)) & (timestamps<Event(3))]

## here are some alternatives to change the "living" attribute

# use python map function to set the living attribute
list(map(lambda x: x.living(False), result))

# This is a for-loop shorthand
[v.living(False) for v in result]

# apply a vectorized function to all elements of result
np.vectorize(lambda x: x.living(False))(result)

# (also pandas' df.apply())
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. But I wanted to avoid using for loops at all

Comment: okay, that sounds good :-) I added a few non-for-loop options for you